# Why does clang ignore __restrict__?

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, restrict

I just tested a small example to check whether `__restrict__` works in C++ on the latest compilers:

```
void foo(int x,int* __restrict__ ptr1, int& v2) {
   for(int i=0;i<x;i++) {
       if(*ptr1==v2) {
           ++ptr1;
       } else {
           *ptr1=*ptr1+1;
       }
   }
}
```

When trying it on godbolt.org with the latest gcc (gcc8.1 -O3 -std=c++14), the `__restrict__` works as expected: `v2` is loaded only once, since it cannot alias with `ptr1`.

Here are the relevant assembly parts:

```
.L5:
  mov eax, DWORD PTR [rsi]
  cmp eax, ecx # <-- ecx contains v2, no load from memory
  jne .L3
  add edx, 1
  add rsi, 4
  cmp edi, edx
  jne .L5
```

Now the same with the latest clang (clang 6.0.0 -O3 -std=c++14). It unrolls the loop once, so the generated code is much bigger, but here is the gist:

```
.LBB0_3: # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
  mov edi, dword ptr [rsi]
  cmp edi, dword ptr [rdx] # <-- restrict didn't work, v2 loaded from memory in hot loop
  jne .LBB0_9
  add rsi, 4
  mov edi, dword ptr [rsi]
  cmp edi, dword ptr [rdx] # <-- restrict didn't work, v2 loaded from memory in hot loop
  je .LBB0_12
```

Why is this the case? I know that `__restrict__` is non-standard and the compiler is free to ignore it, but it seems to be a very fundamental technique for getting the last bit of performance out of ones code, so I doubt that clang simply does not support it while supporting and ignoring the keyword itself. So, what is the issue here? Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Probably worth asking this on the Clang Dev mailing list?

Comment: Maybe because `__restrict__` is never defined in C++ standard and is just a gcc extension?

Comment: And not only is it a GCC extension, it's an extension which can safely be ignored.  It only affects efficiency, not correctness.

Comment: If *"it seems to be a very fundamental technique for getting the last bit of performance out of ones code"* you should also profile the two snippets to verify the actual impact on performances.

Comment: @Bob__: I did. Not for this example, but for examples from our real code. This is why I am playing around with `__restrict__` in the first place. I am not getting paid for premature optimizations ;). We have very tight hot loops and the extra memory load costs us measurable performance.

Comment: @MSalters: I know. Of course it can be ignored. But it is very viable, still. Only because something *can* be ignored does not mean modern compilers do so. clang is usually on top of most compilers when it comes to optimization potential. I just find it strange, would they just have ignored the potential in this case.

Comment: Clang 7 User's Manual does not mention `__restrict__` (nor `__restrict`) at all: https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html. Some info can be found here: [Restrict-qualified pointers in LLVM](https://llvm.org/devmtg/2017-02-04/Restrict-Qualified-Pointers-in-LLVM.pdf).

Comment: @gexicide: But you don't _need_ the keyword. `int local_v2 = v2;` allows the same optimization using Standard C++.

Comment: @MSalters Or, passing `v2` by value.

Comment: @MSalters: Of course it does. In this minimal example. But what if you are in a lambda that is passed to a hot loop and `v2` is captured? Then you cannot put it onto the stack before the loop, as you (i.e., the lambda) don't control the loop.

Comment: Well, you might consider expanding the example to a less minimal snippet. While loosing generality (of the question itself), you may find at least a workaround for your actual problem, I think.

Answer (score 13):

*So many useless comments...*

This seems to be a bug in Clang alias analyzer. If you change type of `v2` to `short` compiler happily removes it from the loop based on type-based aliasing rules:

```
for.body:                                         ; preds = %for.inc, %for.body.lr.ph
  %i.09 = phi i32 [ 0, %for.body.lr.ph ], [ %inc, %for.inc ]
  %ptr1.addr.08 = phi i32* [ %ptr1, %for.body.lr.ph ], [ %ptr1.addr.1, %for.inc ]
  %1 = load i32, i32* %ptr1.addr.08, align 4, !tbaa !5
  %cmp1 = icmp eq i32 %1, %conv
  br i1 %cmp1, label %if.then, label %if.else
```

But with original loop you get the same alias set for both memory references, which is why middle-end can't optimize it:

```
  %i.08 = phi i32 [ %inc, %for.inc ], [ 0, %for.body.preheader ]
  %ptr1.addr.07 = phi i32* [ %ptr1.addr.1, %for.inc ], [ %ptr1, %for.body.preheader ]
  %0 = load i32, i32* %ptr1.addr.07, align 4, !tbaa !1
  %1 = load i32, i32* %v2, align 4, !tbaa !1
  %cmp1 = icmp eq i32 %0, %1
  br i1 %cmp1, label %if.then, label %if.else
```

Note the `!tbaa !1` attached to both memory references which means that compiler couldn't distinguish memory accessed by either of them. It seems that `restrict` annotation has been lost along the way...

I encourage you to reproduce this with latest Clang and file a bug in [LLVM Bugzilla](https://bugs.llvm.org/) (be sure to cc Hal Finkel).